# Why does malleability and ductility of interstitial carbides decrease?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, lattices

Why does the malleability and ductility of interstitial carbides decrease? I read the following in my book, but I am not able to find what is the reason for the same. Why does this happen? Is it to do with the change in lattice properties?

I read this in JD Lee (adapted version by Sudarshan Guha), it stated after a section on interstitial carbides

> The hardness and density are increased for these (interstitial) carbides while malleability and ductility are decreased.

Comment: I read that in JD Lee (adapted version by Sudarshan Guha), it stated after a section on interstitial carbides, "The hardness and density are increased for these (interstitial) carbides while malleability and ductility are decreased"

Comment: In order for a metal to be malleable or ductile, metal atoms must move relative to each other. The carbon atoms intercalate into the metal lattice and form more bonds between the metal atoms (via the bridging C). Can you see why that might affect malleability and ductility?

Comment: @Andrew Yeah makes sense to me!